# Windows 7 Qt Creator libqxt

Tags: windows, qt, build, libqxt

> SDK: Qt Creator 2.4.1 (Qt 4.7.4 (32 bit)) running on Windows 7 
>   Software: libqxt 
>   Final target platform: Harmattan (Nokia N9)

I am developing an application that is suppose to use qt-Brisa which in turn uses libqxt so I am trying to install libqxt.

In the end I am doing a Nokia N9 (Harmattan) application so I need static library of libqxt

However I get problems when trying to install libqxt both if I try the command prompt or with  Qt Creator.

What is the correct approach,  I assume using the Qt Creator is the correct way to build it?

### Try 1

Using command Prompt approach (according to http://dev.libqxt.org/libqxt/wiki/user_guide)

```
C:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2010\bin

configure.bat -static -no-db -debug_and_release
   Testing for qmake...
   Testing for mingw32-make...
   Testing for nmake...
   Testing for GNU make...
       Using GNU make.
   Testing for optional external libraries.
   If tests fail, some features will not be available.
   Testing for Zero Conf...
       Zero Conf disabled.
   Configuration successful.
   Generating makefiles...
Project MESSAGE: building docs
Project MESSAGE: building core module
Project MESSAGE: building widgets module
Project MESSAGE: building network module
Project MESSAGE: building sql module
Project MESSAGE: building web module
Reading C:/temp/Project/libqxt/libqxt/tools/3rdparty/qdoc3/qdoc3.pro
Reading C:/temp/Project/libqxt/libqxt/src/core/core.pro
Reading C:/temp/Project/libqxt/libqxt/src/widgets/widgets.pro
Project MESSAGE: Warning: unknown QT: widgets
Project MESSAGE: Warning: unknown QT: widgets
Project MESSAGE: Warning: unknown QT: widgets
Reading C:/temp/Project/libqxt/libqxt/src/designer/designer.pro
Project MESSAGE: Warning: unknown QT: widgets
Project MESSAGE: Warning: unknown QT: widgets
Project MESSAGE: Warning: unknown QT: widgets
Project MESSAGE: Warning: unknown QT: widgets
Project MESSAGE: Warning: unknown QT: widgets
Project MESSAGE: Warning: unknown QT: widgets
Reading C:/temp/Project/libqxt/libqxt/src/network/network.pro
Reading C:/temp/Project/libqxt/libqxt/tools/jsonrpcclient/jsonrpcclient.pro
Reading C:/temp/Project/libqxt/libqxt/src/sql/sql.pro
Reading C:/temp/Project/libqxt/libqxt/src/web/web.pro
   Makefiles generated. Run make now.

make
Makefile:280: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.
```

Why is it using GNU make and not qmake or am I doing somethign wrong ?

### Try 2

Using Qt Creator

I also tried to load the libqxt project into the Creator (which I would like to prefer) 
but the compile output windows show the following

```
 11:05:50: Running build steps for project libqxt...
 11:05:50: Starting: "c:\qtsdk\desktop\qt\4.8.1\msvc2010\bin\qmake.exe"
 C:\temp\Project\libqxt\libqxt\libqxt.pro -r -spec win32-msvc2010 "CONFIG+=declarative_debug"
 WARNING: features.path is not defined: install target not created

 11:05:50: The process "c:\qtsdk\desktop\qt\4.8.1\msvc2010\bin\qmake.exe" exited normally.
 11:05:50: Starting: "C:\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" 

 jom 1.0.6 - empower your cores

 11:05:51: The process "C:\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited normally.
```

But that did not compile either  
(WARNING: features.path is not defined: install target not created)

When it compiles, how do I "add" the libqxt to the rest of the Qt environment so another project can "see" the libqxt libraries, is it by "Deploy All" ?

Regards Stefan

Comment: I'm currently having the same problem " ... is not defined: install target not created". But that seems related to the fact that my .pro uses INSTALLS += ...Files...  Honestly, your Try 1 is pretty much useless, but I'd like to see your .pro file, that's where the problem lies I believe. I'm trying to fix it as well.